# Finding the length of c

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am not sure if that is an easy or hard question, can c be calculated in this scenario where a and b are known. Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, $c$ cannot be calculated if $a$ and $b$ are known. Let be be $x$ cm. Extend a right angle from $b$ as far as possible. Complete the right triangle and mark off $a$. Note that $c$ depends on how far you extend the right angle from $b$.

Comment: It isn't explicitly given in the problem, but presumably $a$ is half the length of the hypotenuse.

Comment: no isn't it, that is the issue :)

Comment: is there a way to solve it in this case if there isn't a condition on a?

Comment: @khaled If there's no condition on $a$, then clearly there's no way to know what $c$ is. The best you could do is give lower and upper bounds: $c \le a \le \sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway!!

Comment: ... and looking more closely at the diagram, $a$ is definitely more than half of the hypotenuse. So either it's a very poor diagram, or $a$ is arbitrary and there is no way to know $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Query ambiguous.  Depending on how query (i.e. drawing) interpreted, $c$ is either *known* or *unknown*.

Let $\theta$ denote the angle formed by the two line segments whose lengths are labeled $a$ and $c$.  Presumed that $\theta$ and these two line segments form an *inner* right triangle.

Presumed that diagram indicates that $b$ is the leg of an *outer* right triangle, where $c$ is a portion of the other leg and $a$ is a portion of the hypotenuse.

Then, it is clear that $c$ is known if and only if $\theta$ is known.

The question is whether there is some relationship between $a$ and the hypotenuse.  For example, if it is to be presumed that the hypotenuse has length $(2a)$, then $\sin(\theta) = (b/2a)$ which implies that $\theta$ is known, which implies that $c$ is known.

Alternatively, if the hypotenuse of the *outer* right triangle is **unknown**, then $\theta$ can **not** possibly be known, which implies that $c$ can **not** be known.